# How to upgrade IBM Watson's Python version?

Tags: python, upgrade, ibm-watson

Homework is a python notebook project in Watson. Homework provides below codes for function get_basketball_stats(link="..."). However it return erroneous result: dictionary's value and key are dis-matched, i.e. Key "PPG" is given "GP"'s values.

I tried the same codes in google Colab. The result is correct. Google colab python version is 3.6.7. I suspect that the outdated python version in Watson (3.5.5) causes the erroneous dictionary, and hence I ask the question here: how to upgrade Watson's python version?

```
def get_basketball_stats(link='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Jordan'):
# read the webpage 
response = requests.get(link)
# create a BeautifulSoup object to parse the HTML 
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
# the player stats are defined  with the attribute CSS class set to 'wikitable sortable'; 
#therefore we create a tag object "table"
table=soup.find(class_='wikitable sortable')
```

#the headers of the table are the first table row (tr) we create a tag object that has the first row
    headers=table.tr
    #the table column names are displayed  as an abbreviation; therefore we find all the abbr tags and returs an Iterator
    titles=headers.find_all("abbr")
    #we create a dictionary  and pass the table headers as the keys 
    data = {title['title']:[] for title in titles}
   #we will store each column as a list in a dictionary, the header of the column will be the dictionary key

```
#we iterate over each table row by fining each table tag tr and assign it to the objed
for row in table.find_all('tr')[1:]:

    #we iterate over each cell in the table, as each cell corresponds to a different column we all obtain the correspondin key corresponding the column n 
    for key,a in zip(data.keys(),row.find_all("td")[2:]):
        # we append each elment and strip any extra HTML contnet 
        data[key].append(''.join(c for c in a.text if (c.isdigit() or c == ".")))

# we remove extra rows by finding the smallest list     
Min=min([len(x)  for x in data.values()])
#we convert the elements in the key to floats 
for key in data.keys():
    data[key]=list(map(lambda x: float(x), data[key][:Min]))
return data
```

I expect the keys to match their corresponding values in Watson like Google Colad does.

Comment: Do you mean with "Watson" the service "Watson Studio" or something else?

Comment: Yes, I mean in "Watson Studio".

Comment: Select a different kernel and assign it to the notebook...?

Comment: Thank you @ data_henrik! Using Google's colab produced right data. It looks to me that the problem is caused by outdated version of Python in Watson Studio.